# legendre's polynomial problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y$ be a polynomial solution of the differential equation

$$(1-x^2)y^{''}-2xy^{'}+6y=0$$

if $y(1)=2$, then the value of the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}e^{y^2}dx$ is?

how to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Legendre differential equation. Its polynomial solution is $y=\alpha P_2(x) = \alpha \cdot \frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$.

If $y(1)=2$, then it follows that $y=3x^2-1$. And thus

$$\int_{-1}^1 e^{y^2}dx=\int_{-1}^1 e^{(3x^2-1)^2}dx$$

I leave it to others to evaluate this integral.

Comment: the solution can be $\frac{1}{2} (3x^2-1)+1$ right? why do you take specifically $\alpha \cdot y_2(x)$

Comment: @s1mple $\alpha$ can be any (complex) number and then still $\alpha P_2(x)$ is a solution. The supplied proviso $y(1) =2$ then helps to determine $\alpha$. It turns out that then $\alpha = 2$. Predictable if you think about the fact that Legendre polynomials are 'normalized' by $P_n(1)=1$.